# Order Pages by Custom Field Value

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, custom-fields

I have set up several pages including a custom field with a numerical value. When I am querying the pages I want to display them ordered by the custom field numerical value from lowest to highest.

This is the code I am using:

```
<?php 
    query_posts(array('showposts' => -1, 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'meta_key' => 'price-medium', 'order' => 'ASC', 'post_parent' => 1286, 'post_type' => 'page'));
    ?>
```

For som reason the sorting is not working and pages are being shown scattered not by price order.

Can anyone have any idea or suggestions in how to go about this ?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to sort this issue by changing the

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value'
```

to

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
```